# Is "aa" an even or odd palindrome?

Tags: palindrome

I came across a question with a solution that says this:

The context-free grammar (CFG) for palindromes of even length was
given: Σ = {a, b}, P → a P a | b P b | ε

Give a context-free grammar (CFG) for palindromes that allows odd-length palindromes.

Solution: P → a a | bPb | a | b | ε

But I don't understand how "aa" is an odd-length palindrome? It's length is definitely two, unless I'm seeing it wrong. They say it's the right answer, and if it is, I need to know the reason why since I don't understand it.

Comment: Obviously it is a misprint. Should have been $aPa$. Doesn't make sense otherwise. Also, the new grammar allows for both odd and even length palindromes. It is not just odd.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I have a question. By new grammar do you mean this one - P → a a | bPb | a | b | ε? If yes, could you explain how it works for even length palindromes as well?

Comment: The grammar is $P\to aPa|bPb|a|b|\varepsilon$. It gives palindromes of all lengths because it allows you to have either of $a,b,\varepsilon$ in "the middle" when you finish developing the first two rules.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you very much! :)